# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'times_scalar'

Tags: python

This is my Linear System code. The `times_scalar` function is defined in the `Vector` object. When executing the `multiply_coefficient_and_row` function, I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'times_scalar'`. I tried different things including converting the tuple into a list and back to a tuple but had no success.

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
from copy import deepcopy
from Vector import Vector
from Plane import Plane
getcontext().prec = 30

class LinearSystem(object):

    ALL_PLANES_MUST_BE_IN_SAME_DIM_MSG = 'All planes in the system should live in the same dimension'
    NO_SOLUTIONS_MSG = 'No solutions'
    INF_SOLUTIONS_MSG = 'Infinitely many solutions'

    def __init__(self, planes):
        try:
            d = planes[0].dimension
            for p in planes:
                assert p.dimension == d

            self.planes = planes
            self.dimension = d

        except AssertionError:
            raise Exception(self.ALL_PLANES_MUST_BE_IN_SAME_DIM_MSG)


    def swap_rows(self, row1, row2):
        self[row1], self[row2] = self[row2], self[row1]


    def multiply_coefficient_and_row(self, coefficient, row):
        n = self[row].normal_vector.coordinates
        k = self[row].constant_term

        new_normal_vector = n.times_scalar(coefficient)
        new_constant_term = k * coefficient

        self[row] = Plane(normal_vector = new_normal_vector, constant_term = new_constant_term)


    def add_multiple_times_row_to_row(self, coefficient, row_to_add, row_to_be_added_to):
        n1 = self[row_to_add].normal_vector.coordinates
        n2 = self[row_to_be_added_to].normal_vector.coordinates

        k1 = self[row_to_add].constant_term
        k2 = self[row_to_be_added_to].constant_term

        new_normal_vector = n1.times_scalar(coefficient).plus(n2)
        new_constant_term = (k1 * coefficient) + k2

        self[row_to_be_added_to] = Plane(normal_vector = new_normal_vector, constant_term = new_constant_term)



    def indices_of_first_nonzero_terms_in_each_row(self):
        num_equations = len(self)
        num_variables = self.dimension

        indices = [-1] * num_equations

        for i,p in enumerate(self.planes):
            try:
                indices[i] = p.first_nonzero_index(p.normal_vector.coordinates)
            except Exception as e:
                if str(e) == Plane.NO_NONZERO_ELTS_FOUND_MSG:
                    continue
                else:
                    raise e

        return indices


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.planes)


    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.planes[i]


    def __setitem__(self, i, x):
        try:
            assert x.dimension == self.dimension
            self.planes[i] = x

        except AssertionError:
            raise Exception(self.ALL_PLANES_MUST_BE_IN_SAME_DIM_MSG)


    def __str__(self):
        ret = 'Linear System:\n'
        temp = ['Equation {}: {}'.format(i+1,p) for i,p in enumerate(self.planes)]
        ret += '\n'.join(temp)
        return ret

class MyDecimal(Decimal):
    def is_near_zero(self, eps=1e-10):
        return abs(self) < eps
```

and from the `Vector` class this `times_scalar` function:

```
def times_scalar(self, c):
    new_coordinates = [Decimal(c) * x for x in self.coordinates]
    return Vector(new_coordinates)
```

Comment: you use `n.times_scalar()` so do `print(n)` to see what you have in `n` - it seems you have `tuple` instead of `Vector`

Comment: Thanks. I know that. I used  n = self[row].normal_vector, it returns Vector and it works in the Shell but NOT when executing as a function. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: but in code you use `normal_vector.coordinates`, not `normal_vector` so you get `normal_vector.coordinates.times_scalar()`